# Does there exist an r-regular graph (r≥2) with a unique maximum matching?

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

Akbari, Ghodrati, Hosseinzadeh (2017), *On the structure of graphs having a unique k-factor*, Aust. J. Combin. ([pdf](https://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/69/ajc_v69_p063.pdf)) show:

> ... we prove that there is no r-regular graph (r≥2) with a unique perfect matching.

It seems natural to explore the stronger case:

**Question**: Does there exist an r-regular graph (r≥2) with a unique ***maximum*** matching?

I.e., the same problem with "perfect" replaced by "maximum", thereby including graphs without perfect matchings.

The answer is clearly "no" for r=2 (such graphs are unions of cycles; we can rotate any cycle to give a distinct maximum matching).  For r=3, the answer is "no" for bridgeless cubic graphs, which have a perfect matching (by [Petersen's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen%27s_theorem)) and therefore the above result applies.  I'm not sure beyond this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a maximum matching $M$ and a vertex $v$ not in $M$.  If $v$ has a neighbour $w$ not in $M$, then $M+vw$ is a larger matching. So $v$ has a neighbour $x$ which is in an edge $xy$ of $M$.  Now $M-xy+vx$ is another maximum matching.

Comment: Ah thanks.  I guess I should have worked that one out myself.  (: