# Smallest $3$-regular graph with a unique perfect matching

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, perfect-matchings, regular-graph

What is the smallest 3-regular graph to have a unique perfect matching?

With a large enough number of nodes, it is possible for a 3-regular graph to have no perfect matching (example can be seen in this question [Cubic graphs without a perfect matching and a vertex incident to three bridges](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98385/cubic-graphs-without-a-perfect-matching-and-a-vertex-incident-to-three-bridges) ). So I believe 3-regular graphs with a unique matching likely exists, but I am unsure how to go about constructing and proving what the smallest one is. Likely there is no better answer than to brute force check all the possibilities, so I am hoping someone happens to know what this graph looks like.

Even better: Does anyone know of an online searchable graph database that allows searching for small graphs with certain properties?

Comment: This has a construction for the densest graph for 2n nodes with a unique perfect matching https://mathoverflow.net/questions/226583/densest-graphs-with-unique-perfect-matching Unfortunately this cannot be pared back to a 3-regular graph, as one vertex in this construction is of degree 1, but possibly the construction there could give some related ideas.

Answer (score 11):

There is no such graph.

I have some reading to do as my intuition is off, but the details and a related question are available here:
[Does there exist an r-regular graph (r≥2) with a unique maximum matching?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349421/does-there-exist-an-r-regular-graph-r%E2%89%A52-with-a-unique-maximum-matching)

Akbari, Ghodrati, Hosseinzadeh (2017), *On the structure of graphs having a unique k-factor*, Aust. J. Combin. ([pdf](https://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/69/ajc_v69_p063.pdf)) show:

> ... we prove that there is no r-regular graph (r≥2) with a unique perfect matching.

Comment: The paper of Akbari, Ghodrati, and Hosseinzadeh begins: "Throughout this paper all graphs are finite and simple." Isn't it possible that the "smallest $3$-regular graph with a unique perfect matching" exists and is an infinite graph?

Answer (score 4):

Regarding your second *even better* question, I warmly suggest the [Brendan McKay page on combinatorial objects](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/data/), that gives many kinds of graph examples.